milvus.py: pymilvus.exceptions.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=1, message=Field full_length is not in the hit entity)>
I query a collection in a zilliz milvus db like this:
documents = vector_store.similarity_search_with_score(query)

The query is successful but in line 777 of milvus.py the value result.full_length is retrieved, which is not available:
for result in res[0]:
            data = {x: result.entity.get(x) for x in output_fields}
            doc = self._parse_document(data)
            pair = (doc, result.full_length)
            ret.append(pair)

which then leads to this exception
File "/Users/tilman/LangchainCorsera/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/milvus.py", line 644, in similarity_search
    res = self.similarity_search_with_score(
  File "/Users/tilman/LangchainCorsera/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/milvus.py", line 717, in similarity_search_with_score
    res = self.similarity_search_with_score_by_vector(
  File "/Users/tilman/LangchainCorsera/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/milvus.py", line 777, in similarity_search_with_score_by_vector
    pair = (doc, result.full_length)
  File "/Users/tilman/LangchainCorsera/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymilvus/client/abstract.py", line 588, in __getattr__
    raise MilvusException(message=f"Field {item} is not in the hit entity")
pymilvus.exceptions.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=1, message=Field full_length is not in the hit entity)>

Any clues?

Turned out this was a bug in langchain-community, that was resolved with an update

I think you are trying to fetch full_length field but it's not defined in the output field of milvus.
Check the code how to get output_fields

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The callstack shows:
File "/Users/tilman/LangchainCorsera/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/milvus.py", line 644, in similarity_search
    res = self.similarity_search_with_score(
  File "/Users/tilman/LangchainCorsera/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/milvus.py", line 717, in similarity_search_with_score
    res = self.similarity_search_with_score_by_vector(
  File "/Users/tilman/LangchainCorsera/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/milvus.py", line 777, in similarity_search_with_score_by_vector
    pair = (doc, result.full_length)

But in the langchian source code, the line 777 of milvus.py is "pair = (doc, result.score)"
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.16/libs/community/langchain_community/vectorstores/milvus.py

Did you change your local code of langchain?
